# Setar variável JS em input value HTML

Tags: javascript, html, input

Tenho vários inputs em um HTML, onde os IDs estão corretos. Quero buscar o `value` desses Inputs com essas variáveis de JavaScript, porém somente o Input de `nome` pega o valor da variável! O resto dos inputs ficam vazios:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'api/user/getSession',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            document.getElementById("nome").value = data.nome,
            document.getElementById("perfil").value = data.perfil,
            document.getElementById("empresa").value = data.perfil
        }
    });
```

Comment: Seja mais claro, mal entendi oque você quer fazer; e para ficar mais claro, coloque pelo menos o html do seu pseudo form .

Comment: Se você está utilizando o `jQuery`, por que utilizar `getElementById`? É mais fácil utilizar o seletor `$('#nome').val(data.nome)`;

Comment: cadê os inputs?

Comment: Pke não coloca um console.log(data.d) e veja se o resultado está vindo corretamente. ou mesmo um alert.

Comment: Os inputs são do tipo text? os valores estão chegando na variavel data? para conferir mande um console.log(data.perfil)

Comment: Já estava chegando ok! Obrigada a todos e Wallace Maxters deu certo o seu. Sou n00b em JS e jQuery

Comment: @DanielaMarquesdeMorais bem vinda ao SOpt, que bom que sua pergunta foi respondida, seria interessante registrar sua experiencia, coloque seu codigo html e js, explique sua pergunta, assim que alguem oferecer uma solução e que seja valida ao seu problema, aceite !

Comment: @DanielaMarquesdeMorais Você também pode usar $.each no seu retorno json -> `$.each(data,function(chave, valor) { $('#' + chave).val(valor);
});` (Só uma dica mesmo..., no seu caso você usa uma chave para 2 campos diferentes, ai precisaria de algumas alterações mesmo...)

Comment: Os ids estão corretos? O valor 'data.perfil' está retornando valor?

Comment: @deFreitas Sim. A solução foi jQuery, obrigada

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O seu problema não é no uso do jQuery ou JavaScript, mas sim em virgulas (`,` commas), o correto seria `;` (ponto e virgula - semicolon), veja você fez assim:

```
document.getElementById("nome").value = data.nome,
document.getElementById("perfil").value = data.perfil,
document.getElementById("empresa").value = data.perfil
```

O correto é isto:

```
document.getElementById("nome").value = data.nome;
document.getElementById("perfil").value = data.perfil;
document.getElementById("empresa").value = data.perfil;
```

> Note que o último *ponto e virgula* não é necessário, mas costumamos usar para evitar erros.

No jQuery você também usou virgula:

```
$("#nome").val(data.nome),
$("#perfil").val(data.perfil),
$("#empresa").val(data.perfil)
```

Mesmo que não ocorra o erro, o melhor é usar o `;`:

```
$("#nome").val(data.nome);
$("#perfil").val(data.perfil);
$("#empresa").val(data.perfil);
```

Resultado final:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'api/user/getSession',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        $("#nome").val(data.nome);
        $("#perfil").val(data.perfil);
        $("#empresa").val(data.perfil);
    }
});
```

Comment: Obrigada, tão obvio e NINGUÉM observou isso além de você. Esclarecedor!

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'api/user/getSession',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            $("#nome").val(data.nome),
            $("#perfil").val(data.perfil),
           $("#empresa").val(data.perfil)
        }
    });
```

Comment: Não consigo entender como este código funciona e outro não, você apenas mudou de DOM API para jQuery. Poderia explicar qual a diferença?

Comment: I have no idea, sendo que é praticamente a mesma coisa mas só funfou assim.

Comment: I have an answer for you!

Comment: Daniela, você apagou a outra pergunta, sobre o botão que executava um `alert` inesperado, eu ia lhe fazer uma pergunta, quando o BackBone renderiza o teu template ele gera mais de um `<button>`?

Comment: É exibido somente os botões pertencentes da página (recuperar senha e salvar). Não entendi como e por quê mas acabou entrando no evento errado.

Comment: Não é isto que eu quis dizer, o que eu quero dizer é que IDs não podem repetir, se o botão aparece mais de uma vez, são IDs repetidos gerados e isto pode ter desencadeado o problema.

Comment: Provavelmente! Restaurei a pergunta para ter esta resposta lá.